# X remains Subspace under Compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We just had the definition of compactification in our lecture, which says that Y must be compact and X must be a dense and open subspace of X. However in his Notes he gave the Definition so that X must only be a dense, open subset. My question now is if this condition is necessary for compactification or if it can be put down.

I am especially interested if compact Sets wouldnt necessarily remain compact if X only needs to be a subset.

Comment: Didn't you cite the same condition twice? $X$ is a dense open subspace of $Y$?

Comment: I think he distinguishes between subspace and subset @Christoph

Comment: Oh I see, then the answer is that every subset becomes a subspace with the subspace topology. So "subset" and "subspace" are the same in topological spaces.

Answer (score 2):

No, if $Y$ is a compactification of $X$, then $X$ needs to be a subspace of $Y$.  That is, the topology that $X$ had to begin with must coincide with its topology as a subspace of $Y$.

On the other hand, the definition of "compactification" that I'm accustomed to does not require $X$ to be open in $Y$.  I think that will be the case in general only when $X$ is locally compact.

Comment: Yes, since a subspace of a locally compact Hausdorff space is locally compact iff it's open in its own closure, $X$ is open in $Y$ iff it's locally compact.

Answer (score 0):

The term "subspace" in the context of topology means, essentially, a subset when considered with the induced topology.

In particular, every subspace is a subset of the space, and every subset is a subspace of the space.